# How to merge two sets of timeseries together while maintaining the same returns?

Tags: time-series

I have a question about merging two sets of timeseries without causing much havoc.
I have to merge dataset 1 into dataset 2.

Problem is:

1. The levels are different. (Ex: dataset 1 is moving between 2 - 3 while dataset 2 is moving between 5 - 6)
2. I have to maintain the same consistency in the returns from dataset 2 into dataset 1 when merging but also gradually increase the level so that it moves from the 2 - 3 range to 5 - 7 range.
   This merging period should not be more than 2 months.

Could anyone advise what is the best approach to this (mathematically) as this needs to be done in excel?
Thanks.

Comment: I think it might help to explain what you are going to do with this merged set. Why is there a need to align the levels gradually?

Comment: Hi, this will be used in risk factor calculations. The need to merge dataset1 into 2 gradually is to ensure that this adjustment will cause as little changes as possible to the existing data

Comment: Technically, you can use any method of gradually weighting returns, no? Although you have not asked for it, I would rather suggest to do this without fudging the data but by calculating risk under a+b both data sets, and c the combined set and then analyzing and reporting the effects. Feels like a cleaner and more transparent approach to me, at least.